# 4x4 matrix rotation unexpected: 200°+45°=115°

Tags: swift, matrix, scenekit, arkit, simd

I would like to make a rotation using 4x4 matrix in Swift, but it has unexpected behavior: 200 degrees + 45 degrees = 115 degrees, and not 245

```
    let degree200 = Angle(degrees: 200).radians
    let degree45 = Angle(degrees: 45).radians
    // 200 degrees + 45 degrees
    let rotationMatrix = float4x4(simd_quatf(angle: Float(degree200+degree45), axis: SIMD3<Float>(0, 1, 0)))
    // it prints 115 degree, and not 245
    print(Angle(radians: Double(simd_quatf(rotationMatrix).angle)).degrees)
```

Comment: Rotating by 245° around `[0, 1, 0]` is the same as rotating by 115° around `[0, -1, 0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that's a typo, and you in fact meant -115 degrees? *(remainder(245, 360))* When using quaternions & Matrices to express orientations, you can only expect to see values of -180 to +180 degrees when converting those values back to Euler angles.

In general it is impossible to convert back to Euler angles from either a quaternion or matrix and get the original input values back. You either store the original Euler angles and present those to the user, or you will have to have a known starting Euler value and apply an Euler filter to obtain approximately correct results.

The only *correct* way to get your expected result is to NOT print the value after conversion to quats:

```
print((degree200 + degree45). degrees)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I know 115 and 245 are 360. Just a guess but maybe you're rotating the wrong way?? Maybe try negative values and see what happens.